# how to launch new activity based on spinner value

Tags: android, android-spinner

i am building this app that has a spinner and button on the first activity, but i have other activities which are lauched based on spinner value. but the problem now is when i click on button nothing happens, what could be wrong? this is my code

```
public class ow extends AppCompatActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ow);
       Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.tac);

        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        final String text = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (text.equals("GTB")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ow.this, gtb.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else if(text.equals("ZENITH")){
                    Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),z.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_ow);
       Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.tac);

        final Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);  
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if (text.equals("GTB")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ow.this, gtb.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else if(text.equals("ZENITH")){
                    Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),z.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

        });

    }}
```

Comment: i cant really spot the different between my code and yours, what was wrong with mine

Comment: `String text = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();` moved into event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Your `OnClickListener` is `Anonymous` type. The string value is supplied to it in `onCreate` which is default value, probably `null`. Use `spinner` as class member and access selected item value inside `onClick` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write following line on **button click listener**

```
final String text = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

like:

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if (text.equals("GTB")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ow.this, gtb.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else if(text.equals("ZENITH")){
                    Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),z.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

        });
```

Hope it will works.

Answer (score 0):

U have to create a spinner event.

**For example:**

```
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.opcoes,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, 
        View view, int position, long l) {

            String item = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

   Switch(item){
   case item1:
   Intent yourAcitivity = new Intent(this, yourAcitivity.class);
            startActivity(yourAcitivity );
   case item2:
   Intent yourSecondAcitivity = new Intent(this, yourSecondAcitivity.class);
            startActivity(yourSecondAcitivity);
    //Keep adding items.

}

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```